# Request for Changes to the Author List

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, authorship

I need to change the corresponding author in my paper. The journal asked to submit a form which is about changes in the author list. The text is as follows :
[image]

Do I still need to submit this form. I have just changed the corresponding authorship from 1st author to second author. I have not added any new authors or change the authors order.

Comment: I agree that this is a little unclear. At the beginning the wording suggests that "author list" and "order of authors" might be distinct, because the sentence with "the list and order of authors" is written in a way that suggests "the list" refers to "author list". But maybe the object for "the" is actually all of "list and order of authors". It's not clear to me, and it would have been better to explicitly use "list of authors" and "order of authors" as separate notions, and be clear whether one and/or both are what is meant by "updated author list" (a new phrase BTW, not previously used).

Comment: *(to continue)* That said, I agree with @Especially Lime that what you are doing doesn't qualify as "Original Author List" not-equal "Updated Author List", as your proposed change has no effect for any of the interpretations of what an "updated author list" might mean -- addition and/or subtraction of authors, OR change in order of authors, OR both.

Answer (score 4):

This form doesn't seem to apply, as the list of authors is the same. Being corresponding author has no direct connection to how much you have contributed, so you don't normally need to justify the choice of who it is.

I would simply have the current corresponding author email the editor (usually there is a way to do this through the system) and ask to change the corresponding author. I have done this without problems in the past.

Answer (score -1):

The above form does not apply to changes in corresponding author. If you have to submit a reply letter than you will just have to do it in the portal. If the article is published than you just have to email the administrative staff assigned to your manuscript.